# What is the function of cyclic sleep mode in Router API MODE in XBee XCTU software?

Tags: arduino, sleep, xbee, zigbee, sleep-mode

I am using XBee pro series 2.

I have read in many forums that ZigBee routers do not support sleep mode. But I have seen in XCTU software that we can still set the sleep mode (e.g. cyclic sleep mode etc.).

Does XBee pro series 2 support sleep mode ROUTER devices?

Answer (score 0):

ZigBee routers are mains powered devices that do not sleep in order to route data in the network.  The XBee Pro modules have a sleep option (with the SM command), but if sleep is enabled, the module joins the network as an end device.  If it was functioning as a router when sleep is enabled, it will leave the network before trying to join as an end device.

Comment: Can router NOT sniff regularly to see if there is some serial data or not on its radio if SM is enabled? I was thinking router cyclic mode option was given to make a sniffing router. Is this understanding not correct?